# ExecuteSqlCommand throws Incorrect syntax near @p0, but in ssms it executes succesfully

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I wrote a SQL command which inserts multiple rows. The formattable string that generates here, executes successfully if copy/paste it to SSMS and run, but inside the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method it throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in App.Api.dll but was not handled in user code. Incorrect syntax near '@p0'

which typically tells that something is wrong with a script, but it's not that case. Maybe somebody knows what is the problem?

```
var elements = new List<Discount>();

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    elements.Add(new Discount
                     {
                         Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                         SomeField0 = $"D- {i}",
                         SomeField1 = i,
                         SomeField2 = i / 100
                     });
}

string values = String.Join(", ", elements.Select(item => $"('{item .Id}', 
            '{item.SomeField0}', {item.SomeField1}, {item .SomeField2})"));
          FormattableString formString = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].TableName Values {values}";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(formString);
```

FormattableString value:

```
{
 INSERT INTO [dbo].SomeTable Values
 ('852106e6-33e7-4f82-b00d-5c6e662d3c91', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('68d5720a-4db8-437d-babb-d9e408548699', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('fa2fc7ff-f355-4df5-928b-b3e8a77d1341', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('503bc3ff-fb1f-4203-b098-d981093d2b5d', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('0c5b61f6-1f93-4a40-8c1e-48194f8e8ca1', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('02d9558c-623b-4bd7-86c5-12e3202fcdf6', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('883bbdf2-dc15-41b0-9a39-5af9d56e15f2', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('900d0beb-cc9b-4ff6-a74c-742a032ee9e1', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('ceb5eb75-694b-44da-bf3a-cd2fd8741308', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0),
 ('eb39a23b-2f32-4628-a111-68630291fd00', 'Acc - 0', 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: try to output your formString. I believe there is some typo in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was in FormattableString. Use RawSqlString instead of it :

```
var script = new RawSqlString($"INSERT INTO [dbo].Table VALUES {values}");
```